Sequential Probability Ratio Test of ANOVA
I am running a sequential experiment that consists in 60 units in three treatment arms, so 20 units in each arm. We can assume that in each arm, the values recorded for each unit are normally distributed.
Each unit "grows" over time, and I wish to detect whether there's evidence that the means in each arm are different. I want to do some kind of ANOVA every hour of the experiment.
Here is what some of the data looks like:

I've looked into the theory behind sequential probability ratio tests (SPRT), but I think the classic SPRT differs from my setup in several ways:

SPRT assumes new observations (on new units) come in over time, whereas I observe the same units over time
SPRT assumes we are comparing two simple hypotheses, whereas I am just interested in rejecting the null of equal means

I've tried plotting the ANOVA's p-value over time (it decreases), and also the log-likelihood ratio of a full linear model vs a model with just an intercept over time (it either remains flat around 0, or grows indefinitely).
I have read the following papers:

Sequential Analysis of Variance: Increasing Efficiency of Hypothesis Testing
A Maximized Sequential Probability Ratio Test for
Drug and Vaccine Safety Surveillance

But none of them seems to quite apply to my case.
Can someone point me to the right way to carry out this sequential test?
